# Why do I always get one node inside the tree?

Tags: javascript

Here is what Class looks like:

```js
const Node = class grahpNode {
  constructor(data, id, family) {
    this.data = data;
    this.right = null;
    this.left = null;
    this.parent = null; //helps us to go to the prev page on the app
    this.id = id; //unique identifier of the page
    this.family = family; //it tracks of which page is part of which
  }
}

const Tree = class TreeClass {
    constructor() {
      this.root = null;
      this.current = this.root; //helps us keep track of where we are
      this.currentTail = this.current; //helps us to insert data
      this.direction = true; //it directs us for insertion, true for left, false for right
      this.nodes = 0;
    }

    //Mehtods of the tree data structure:

    //inserting nodes to the tree
    insertNode(data, direction = this.direction) {
      let leftRight = direction ? "left" : "right";
      if (!this.root)
        return this.currentTail = this.current = this.root = new Node(data, this.nodes++, 0);
      console.log(true); //the issue is here true has never got console logged??
      if (this.currentTail[leftRight]) {
        this.currentTail = this.currentTail[leftRight];
        this.insertNode(data, direction);
      } else {
        this.currentTail[leftRight] = new Node(data, this.nodes, this.current.id);
        this.currentTail[leftRight].parent = this.currentTail;
        this.nodes++;
      };
    }
  }
```

**Why do I get always one node inside the tree even after the first insertion? It just gets updated and we have always just the root.**

Kindly help me, I really got stuck here.

Comment: Hard to answer without the first call to insertNode.

Comment: When I test it now with 4 users and tried to insert them I didn't get the last one with two users it's just the root no second one and the weird thing is that this.node is the exact number of users?

Comment: How did you know that you always get one node inside the tree? Can you please show us the codes?

Comment: Actually the data structure was almost fine I just added some patches the problem was in the react component I used a state variable that represents both the state and the tree in the same time and it got confusing when I apply the insertNode method the state var doesn't change!? I mean nodes stays always one and then I had to separate them and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revised version of your code (with some log statements) that inserts nodes successfully.

If any part is confusing, I'm happy to add detail.

```js
class Node {
  constructor(data, id, family, parent=null) {
    this.data = data;
    this.id = id;
    this.family = family;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.right = null;
    this.left = null;
  }
}

class Tree {
  constructor() {
    this.root = null;
    this.currentHead = this.root;
    this.currentTail = this.currentHead;
    this.direction = true;
    this.nodes = 0;
  }

  insertNode(data, direction = this.direction) {
    const dir = direction ? "left" : "right";
    if (!this.root){
      // Inserts root (id:0, family:0), and increments this.nodes
      console.log(`- Created root node (${data})`);
      return this.currentTail = this.currentHead = this.root = new Node(data, this.nodes++, 0);
    }
    if (this.currentTail[dir]) {
      // Child of currentTail already exists -- tries to insert grandchild instead
      console.log(`(${this.currentTail.data}.${dir} is full, trying ${this.currentTail[dir].data}.${dir})`);
      this.currentTail = this.currentTail[dir];
      this.insertNode(data, direction);
    }
    else {
      // Inserts child of currentTail, and increments this.nodes
      console.log(`- Inserted ${data} at ${this.currentTail.data}.${dir}`);
      this.currentTail[dir] = new Node(data, this.nodes++, this.currentHead.id, this.currentTail);
      return this.currentTail;
    };
  }
}

const tree = new Tree();
tree.insertNode("node1");
tree.insertNode("node2");
tree.insertNode("node3");

console.log("\nAll nodes:");
logLeftDescendantsOnly(tree.root);

function logLeftDescendantsOnly(node){
  if(node){
    const {id, data, left} = node;
    console.log(`{ id:${id}, data:'${data}' }`);
    logLeftDescendantsOnly(left)
  }
}
```

Comment: After u added the currentHead now I understand the data structure better thanks for your time I really appreciate it